# Why does gevent give "Too many open files" error during load testing?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, load-testing, gevent

I have a setup consisting of nginx, gunicorn, and django. All these run through docker containers. In django, when a request comes, I save image files that are sent through request.

Since my code is IO bound, I wanted to use gevent, however, during load tests it gives "Error at ...[Errno 24] Too many open files:" unless i make worker-connections 2, which is too low.

I've researched this error, some people suggest increasing ulimit -n, but by default the container has 1048576 limit. It doesn't allow for more. I've also tried using eventlet instead of gevent, but the error is the same.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNP6d.jpg)

Error traces back to this part:

```
with open(path, "wb") as f:
            f.write(imgfile)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Whilst the error may have occurred at the code you've shown, it's almost certainly due to poor coding practice elsewhere in your program - i.e., the limit (whatever it is) has already been reached and when you try to open a new file, the exception arises

Comment: @AlbertWinestein The code snippet is the only part I open a file, is there a possibility that something else triggers this?